# Probability of finding the right number

Tags: probability

Let's say that John, Paul and Peter want to guess a number, which can be 1, 2 or 3. John will go first, then Paul.

- First, John tries to guess.

  - If he says the right number, he wins
  - If not, Paul will try
- Paul tries to guess

  - If he says the right number, he wins.
  - If not, Peter wins

Each one of them knows what each other is saying, so they won't repeat a wrong number.
What are the probabilities of each one to win? 33%?

I need help!

Comment: Yes, it turns out to be $1/3$. One can get the wrong answer by confusing contitional and unconditional probabilities.

Comment: Paul is smart @tpdietz

Comment: @AndréNicolas are you sure?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: I think the most obvious approach is to calculate Paul's probability of wining, which is conditional on John choosing poorly.  But I think it is slightly easier to consider Peter's probability of winning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John guesses correctly with probability $\frac{1}{3}$; he wins if and only if he guesses correctly; so his win probability is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Paul guesses correctly (conditional on John's incorrect guess) with probability $\frac{1}{2}$; he wins if and only if he gets the right number and John gets the wrong number, so he wins with probability $\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{3}$.

Peter gets the remaining probability: $\frac{1}{3}$.

---

There was some work to do to find that answer! As far as I can see, it wasn't "totally obvious" by some kind of symmetry answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider each sequence of guesses as a permutation.  Also, consider the case where the winner is not announced before all people have guessed.  (After all, if more people guess after someone has already won, it doesn't change the odds that the person has won)

Of the six possible permutations, each person will have guessed $1$ one third of the time, each person will have guessed $2$ one third of the time, etc... Furthermore, each of these outcomes are equally likely.

Now, whichever number happens to be the winning number, in exactly one third of the outcomes, John wins.  Similarly, in exactly one third of the outcomes Peter wins. etc...

All players have probability $\frac{1}{3}$ of winning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that our three contestants make their decisions about which number to guess in a completely random fashion.

John has a $0.33...$ chance to win since only one of the three numbers is correct.

Next, Paul has a 50% chance of winning since he knows it cannot be John's guess (if John is wrong). NOTE: this 50% chance only exists if John fails. In other words, Paul's chance of winning is the chance John fails times the chance Paul wins: $0.66...*0.5=0.33...$

Finally, Peter. Similarly, Peter's chance of winning is the chance that both Paul and John fail. If this is the case, then Peter has 100% chance of guessing correctly since only 1 number remains. IE: $0.66...*0.5=0.33...$

In other words, we can show that all three men have the same probability of winning, $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: I highly recommend getting out of the habit of writing $33\%$ when you in fact mean $\frac{1}{3}$.  Those are two very different numbers.  In mathematics, where being precise is so important, it is generally always preferred to write exact answers instead of approximations when available.

Comment: @JMoravtiz edited.

Comment: good advice @JMoravitz